# I am getting error while running react native on android with usb on my phone

Tags: javascript, react-native

> Failed to construct transformer:  Error: EIO: i/o error, read
> at Object.readSync (node:fs:749:3)
> at tryReadSync (node:fs:449:20)
> at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:487:19)
> at getContent (D:\MyCodes\react-native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\worker.js:66:22)
> at Object.worker (D:\MyCodes\react-native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\worker.js:110:20)
> at execFunction (D:\MyCodes\react-native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:137:17)
> at execHelper (D:\MyCodes\react-native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:116:5)
> at execMethod (D:\MyCodes\react-native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:120:5)
> at process.messageListener (D:\MyCodes\react-native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-file-map\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:38:7)
> at process.emit (node:events:513:28) {
> type: 'Error',
> errno: -4070,
> syscall: 'read',
> code: 'EIO'
> }

[Error on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ibt4.jpg)

I wanted to run a basic app. I haven't modified any code as of now.

Comment: you need to run `npm run start` and `npm run android` in two separate command prompts... the run start one will need to be started before the android run

Comment: run start will start the watcher which is what the android app connects to..

Comment: also check if your device is detected with `adb devices`

Comment: This is probably because you are running a project on a very recent node version, try running on an older version like node 16